# How to perform the watch command onto expression with pipes?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, pipe, watch

I learned today the wonderful shuf command:

```
ls | shuf
```

shows me a listing of the working direcotry, but thanks to shuf each time I execute this piped command expression with another order.

So I thought, why not repeat this expression every second anew, and so I tried

```
watch -n1 ls | shuf          (and got no output)
watch -n1 (ls | shuf)        (and got an error)
watch -n1 {ls | shuf}        (and got an error)
```

then I put ls | shuf into its own file and made a script foo out of it.

```
watch -n1 ./foo               (this times it worked)
```

Is it possible to apply the watch command onto a piped command expression without having the expression be made into a script file ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There exists several variants of a watch command, some that spawn a shell to interpret a command line made of the concatenation of the arguments passed to `watch` (with space characters in between). In those you can do:

```
watch 'ls | shuf'
```

same as:

```
watch ls '|' shuf
```

(those `watch` actually run: `"/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "ls | shuf"]` and are quite dangerous in that that second level of interpretation can open the door to bugs and security issues when not anticipated, procps-ng's watch can avoid that behaviour with the `-x` option).

And there are those that just execute the command whose name is given in the first argument with all the arguments as arguments. In those:

```
watch sh -c 'ls | shuf'
```

Comment: when I am in a shell and execute "sh -c" does it mean I start another shell in this shell  ?

Comment: `sh -c 'a command line'` is itself a shell command line that is interpreted by your interactive shell and tell it to run a shell to interpret the other command line passed in that 3rd argument.