# How to use watch command with a piped chain of commands/programs

Tags: bash, pipe, watch

I usually use `watch` Linux utility to watch the output of a command repeatedly every `n` seconds, like in `watch df -h /some_volume/`.

But I seem not to be able to use `watch` with a piped series of command like:

```
$ watch ls -ltr|tail -n 1
```

If I do that, `watch` is really watching `ls -ltr` and the output is being passed to `tail -n 1` which doesn't output anything.

If I try this:

```
$ watch (ls -ltr|tail -n 1)
```

I get

```
$ watch: syntax error near unexpected token `ls'
```

And any of the following fails some reason or another:

```
$ watch <(ls -ltr|tail -n 1)

$ watch < <(ls -ltr|tail -n 1)

$ watch $(ls -ltr|tail -n 1)

$ watch `ls -ltr|tail -n 1)`
```

And finally if do this:

```
$ watch echo $(ls -ltr|tail -n 1)
```

I see no change in the output at the given interval because the command inside `$()` is run just once and the resulting output string is always printed ("watched") as a literal.

**So, how do I make the `watch` command work with a piped chain of commands [other that putting them inside a script]?**

Comment: run `man watch` and scroll down to examples...

Comment: Does https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193270/how-to-perform-the-watch-command-onto-expression-with-pipes answer your question?

Answer (score 341, accepted):

```
watch 'command | othertool | yet-another-tool'
```

Comment: Might be worth noting the generic approach as well `watch sh -c 'command | etc'` particularly looking at the approaches tried in the question.

Comment: @sourcejedi I haven't really figured out why, but this won't always produce the same results.

Comment: An example is `ps aux | grep something` and `watch 'ps aux | grep something'`, they are not producing the same output.

Comment: If you are curious about that, open it as a new question.  For bonus points, include the differing output that you are seeing in the question.

Comment: Startlingly, watch injects "sh -c" normally, to run any command

Comment: use `-x` option to use `/bin/bash -c` instead of `sh -c` for things like redirection operators `command2 < <(command1)`

Answer (score 23):

```
watch -n 1 "ls -lrt | tail -n20; date"
```

let's you pipe and run in a row.

Comment: what is `-n 1` for?

Comment: @NamGVU: Run the command every 1 second

Answer (score 8):

Use a combination of single quotes (`'`) and double quotes (`"`). For example:

```
watch -n 1 "links -dump 127.0.0.1/server-status | grep -e '\S' -Fe 'www.'"
```

Comment: Or vice-versa, or escape them, but works, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to list all files in subdirectories too, you can use find command with exec option.

`watch` will update every 30 seconds and `find` will search for all *.log files in current dir (subdirs included) and will print filenames and their last 10 line:

```
watch -n30 'find . -name "*.log" -print -exec tail -n10 {} \; '
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's say that you run a command and then want to watch it; use:

```
ls -lrt | tail -n20; date
watch "!!"
```

Answer (score 3):

I have just made a little bit more complex pipe chain for watching ElasticSearch nodes' performance. It requires handling variables as well as variable escaping. Hope it may be helpful to others.

```
watch -dn1 'kubectl exec elasticsearch-master-0 -c elasticsearch -- \
  curl -s XGET "localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?h=hp,hc,hm,rp,r,rm,cpu,dup,du,dt,m,n&v" |
  (read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; awk "{print \$NF,\$0}" |
  sort | cut -f2- -d" ")'
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is using inbuilt option `-x`,

```
watch -n 5 -x tail -4 output.log  
watch -n 2 -x ls
```

The first eg. will display the last 4 lines of output.log file every 5 sec., second eg list content every 2 sec.

Comment: Neither `watch -x 'ls -ltr | tail -n 10'` nor `watch -x ls -ltr | tail -n 10` work!

Comment: Maybe you are right. `-x` can be useful to execute something instead of `sh -c`.
For your purpose you can just go with `watch 'ls -ltr | tail -n 10'`

Answer (score 0):

With a very complex command, with mixed single- and double- quotes, it may be better to save the command as a script, and execute that.

Create myCommand.sh

```
vi myCommand.sh
```

Content:

```
#!/bin/bash
# My long command to watch
date; echo "Log files (some in progress):  $(ls -1 */*log | wc -l)"; echo "Current Results: "; grep -h -Po "Log entry: Command 'contains single quotes in string.*" */*log | sort | uniq -c
```

Make executable

```
chmod a+x myCommand.sh
```

The execute it with watch

```
watch -n 30 ./myCommand.sh
```

Comment: Of course, if you have a list of commands (*especially* if they total more than 80 characters), a script file is much more manageable if you put them on separate lines.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' You're not wrong!